# How can the onLoad event be used in a WordPress template?

Tags: html, wordpress, onload

When writing PHP templates for WordPress pages we shouldn't use the `<body>` tag because it already exists in `header.php` which is called in the template.
How than can we use the `onLoad` event within the template?

Since I'm writing more than one template I can't use it in `header.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attach it via the HTML attribute.

Attach it via an non obtrusive event handler. Because WordPress uses jQuery, that's as easy as...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // ....
});
```

Comment: On which file should I add this script to Alex?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Your WordPress' JS in your theme

Comment: So I dont need to enqueue a new script for the above right??